# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode (Telepot retrieve name)

Tags: python, typeerror

I tried to make a bot that retrieve the name of the sender of the chat in a group. I am using Python with Telepot.

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import telepot
>>> response = bot.getUpdates()
pprint(response)
[{u'message': {u'chat': {u'first_name': u'Nick',
                         u'id': 999999999,
                         u'last_name': u'Lee',
                         u'type': u'private'},
           u'date': 1444723969,
           u'from': {u'first_name': u'Nick',
                     u'id': 999999999,
                     u'last_name': u'Lee'},
           u'message_id': 4015,
           u'text': u'Hello'},
u'update_id': 100000000}]
```

When I execute this, it gives me this error

```
sender1 = response[u'message'][u'from'][u'first_name']
sender2 = response[u'message'][u'from'][u'last_name']
```

Error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You can have multiple updates, so `response` is a `list`. You probably need to choose which update you're interested in by indexing the list.

Comment: How do I index the list? I'm sorry, I have just started studying this language.

Comment: It's probably best to get used to reading documentation if you're learning something new. Have a look at the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) instead of a list to access values in a dictionary.  This method returns a value for a given key in a dictionary (or `None` if the key is not available):

```
sender1 = response[0][u'message'][u'from'].get(u'first_name')
sender2 = response[0][u'message'][u'from'].get(u'last_name')

# output:
# >>> print sender1
# u'Nick'
# >>> print sender2
# u'Lee'
```

Comment: `response` is a list.

Comment: @Daniel but your solution using `get` is now irrelevant

Comment: My pleasure @ValenMiriapon; glad it worked for you, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets in a representation mean that you have a list, and lists must be indexed using an integer or slice. Try indexing by `[0]` before attempting to access any contained dictionaries.

Comment: like this?
'sender1 = response[0][u'from'][u'first_name']' this returns me an error index out of bound or something...

Comment: nevermind, I got this error now
sender1 = response[0][u'from'][u'first_name']
KeyError: u'from'

Comment: You can't skip `u'message'`; that's still the key of the dictionary.